# React material-UI custom input for TextField

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, textfield

I'm trying to integrate the material-UI TextField with [react-payment-inputs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-payment-inputs?activeTab=readme) library.

For example I use this library like this:

```
import {usePaymentInputs} from 'react-payment-inputs';    
const { getCardNumberProps} = usePaymentInputs();
<input {...getCardNumberProps({
                    onChange: handleCardChange('number'),
                    onFocus: handleFocus('number'),
                    placeholder: ''
                })}/>
```

I need to pass all input props using the **react-payment-inputs** library
I want to wrap this input with the nice **TextField** **label** effect.
I cannot see how can I send custom input element with custom props to TextField.

This is for example also not working:

```
 <TextField label="First name"
                    InputProps={{
                        input: <input type="text" value={cardInfo.name}
                                      onChange={handleFirstNameChange} onFocus={handleFocus('name')}/>
                    }}
                />
```

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-template-7kj0z)

Comment: To get a custom input component to show on the screen I did `InputProps={{
                    inputComponent: () => <Input name="inputData" onChange={() => console.log("Input was called.")} />
                  }}` within `TextField`. Now I need to make my `Input` component implement the `inputRef` function otherwise `TextField` throws an error each time `Input` gets focus.